# How do I create a custom button/action in a Chromecast expanded controller?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm developing an Android application using the Chromecast SDK v3.

I need to create custom button with a custom action in a Chromecast expanded controller.

I'm aware of the custom button type "@id/cast_button_type_custom," but I'm not sure how to create it. How can I create a button of this type with a custom action? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about what type of customization you can make to the ExpandedController [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced#customize_expanded_controller). As for buttons, there is a fixed [set of button/actions](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced#choose-mini-controller-buttons) that it supports, same set as what the Mini Controller supports. To see an example of how this can be used, checkout the official v3 sample: [CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android).

Answer (score 0):

[Please go through google doc link , it may help to complete task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/uicontroller/UIMediaController)

Add 'onCreate' method in 'ExpandedControlsActivity' and pass 'cast_expanded_controller_activity' , which you can find in framework added depandancy

Note: Dont change widget id.

initialise widget and

> UIMediaController uiMediaController = getUIMediaController();
>   e.g. uiMediaController.bindViewToForward(button_2, 10000);

pass intialised widget accordingly , you can customise your UI for expanded controller